# OracleDUMP file (.datp) issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I received an Oracle 11g database for parsing, but the dump file is in **.datp** format. I have not found anywhere on the internet reference about this type of file linked to OracleDB Schemes. The client's instructions are "have to use Oracle to read it" but:

1- I have superficial knowledge in Oracle

2- this database will be migrated to MySQL

3- I have Oracle XE 11g installed but neither does it have any tools that open this file (at least not apparently).

Any light on how to open and import this database for Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087024/oracledump-file-datp-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a dump file then most likely it's an export from either the old EXP utility or the newer Datapump export (`expdp`).

The file extension is not standard but seems to point to **DAT**a**P**ump. If so you can import it into an Oracle database using Datapump import utility, `impdp`. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL300https://).

If that doesn't work, try original `imp` instead. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#g1070082https://)

Comment: Sadly can't upvote, but I'm accepted it as awnser, ty!